# Setting the parameters for SVM Classification in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, mlr

**Description:**

1. For a data set, I would like to apply `SVM` by using radial basis function (`RBF`) kernel with `Weston, Watkins native multi-class`.
2. The rbf kernel parameter `sigma` must be tuned and I want to use `k-folds cross validation` to do this. I consider a fixed `C`.

**Solution:**

It seems that I can use the nice package [mlr](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/) to do this! So, to tune the `rbf` parameter `sigma` using `CV` for `MSVM` classification, (using this [tutorial](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/tune.html))

```
#While C is fix = 3, define a range to search sigma over it. Search between [10^{-6}, 10^{6}]
num_ps = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("C", values = 3),
  makeNumericParam("sigma", lower = -6, upper = 6, trafo = function(x) 10^x)
)
#Define the Grid search method
ctrl = makeTuneControlGrid()
#Apply the k-folds CV
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3L)

res = tuneParams("classif.ksvm", task = iris.task, resampling = rdesc,
  par.set = num_ps, control = ctrl)
```

**Question:**

For this part

```
res = tuneParams("classif.ksvm", task = iris.task, resampling = rdesc,
      par.set = num_ps, control = ctrl)
```

According to the documentation, by using the integrated learner [classif.ksvm](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/integrated_learners.html#classification-84-), I'm asking to apply the multiclass classification that is defined in the package [ksvm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kernlab/versions/0.9-29/topics/ksvm).

How can I know which method and kernel type are used? I mean, how to force the learner `classif.ksvm` to use the classification type (`kbb-svc`) and the kernel (`rbfdot` ) which are already defined in `ksvm`?

If this is not possible, then how to define a new learner with all of my requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the fixed parameters within the learner. Therefore you first have to create it:

```r
library(mlr)
lrn = makeLearner("classif.ksvm", par.vals = list(C = 3, type = "kbb-svc", kernel = "rbfdot"))
```

Then you only define the parameters that you want to change within the ParamSet

```r
num_ps = makeParamSet(
  makeNumericParam("sigma", lower = -6, upper = 6, trafo = function(x) 10^x)
)
```

Then you can do the tuning as in your example

```r
ctrl = makeTuneControlGrid()
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3L)
res = tuneParams(lrn, task = iris.task, resampling = rdesc, par.set = num_ps, control = ctrl)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just have another question  please! Normally when tuning the parameter sigma with k-folds CV using other packages like caret, we use only the training set. Here using mlr package, do I need to provide only the training set or as in my example, I provide the whole set"IRIS" and the function tuneParams() will handle this and divide the set?

Comment: I mean tuneParams() will tune sigma over the whole set IRIS or it will divide the set firstly and then will tune sigma on the training only?

Comment: It will do the split according to `rdesc` on the whole data (so a 3-fold cv here). This will give you the "optimal" parameters. If you are interested in an unbiased estimate of the tuning performance you have to do nested resampling using `makeTuneWrapper`.